# Range time with interval in php

Tags: php, datetime

I'm creating a daily planner in PHP and every 30 minutes I write a table row and check if an appointment matches. However, I get problem with appointment time partial for example I've to check times: `15:34:58 - 16:34:58`, I don't get match between `15:30` and `16:00`. Here is my code:

```
try {
    $inizio=new DateTime($r["data"]." ".$r["ora"]); // for me is 15:34:58
    $fine=new DateTime($r["data_fin"]." ".$r["ora_fin"]); // for me is 16:34:58
    $timetoCheck=new DateTime(date("Y-m-d")." ".$h.":".$m.":00"); //dinamically change in 15:30 16:00 and so on..
    $intervallo=new DateInterval("PT30M");
    $range=new DatePeriod($inizio, $intervallo, $fine);
    foreach ($range as $fase){
        if (($timetoCheck>=$inizio) and ($timetoCheck<=$fine)) {
            echo $fase->format("H:i:s")." ". $inizio->format("H:i:s")." - ".$fine->format("H:i:s")."<br/><a href='#' id='evento_".$r["key_id"]."'>".$r["titolo"]."</a><br/>";
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ecc){
    $logger->error($ecc->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Please cut the relevant code from this sheet if you want anybody to try to help.

Comment: You probably don't need to be writing a row every 30 minutes, if nothing will be in there.

Comment: @James I dinamically check, I can't know in advance if I'll find something or not  but why my if doenst match appointment between 15:30-16:00 if it starts from 15:34?

Comment: You can add handling to this by way of a condition. If it's `null` then it returned no events. You'll find that if you add a row every 30 minutes for a year, you'll end up with 17531 rows when there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different way of comparing the times?

```
$dateTime = new DateTime("15:40:10");
$startTime = new DateTime("15:30:00");
$endTime = new DateTime("16:00:00");
if ($dateTime->diff($startTime)->format('%R') == '-' && $dateTime->diff($endTime)->format('%R') == '+') {
    // current time is within the appointment period
} else {
    // current time is either before or after the appointment period
}
```

http://php.net/datetime.diff